# Command Prompt Copy

Tags: file, cmd, copy, command, prompt

I have folder name in my directory,

```
packages\Example.1.0.0\Example.dll
packages\Example.2.0.0\Example.dll
packages\Example.3.0.0\Example.dll
```

how to copy file

```
copy /Y "C:\Project\Example.dll" 
"C:\Project\packages\Example.???.???.???\Example.dll"
```

Comment: `copy /Y "C:\Project\Example.dll" "packages\Example.1.0.0\Example.dll"`,...?

Comment: I want to multi file copy and 1.0.0 , 2.0.0 and 3.0.0 .... changeable

Comment: Then you should edit your question and describe that; probably you are searching for `for /D %I in ("packages\Example.?.?.?") do copy "C:\Project\Example.dll" "\Example.dll"`

Comment: @aschipfl somehow, I'd expected a `%I` with the `copy` command...

Comment: Yes of course, @Stephan, it is a typo: `for /D %I in ("packages\Example.?.?.?") do copy "C:\Project\Example.dll" "%~fI\Example.dll"` (if the numberic parts could also consist of more than 1 digit each, replace `Example.?.?.?` by `Example.?*.?*.?*`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd packages\Example.???.???.???
for %%* in (.) do set _currentfolder=%%~nx*
echo %_currentfolder%
copy /Y "C:\Project\Example.dll" 
"C:\Project\packages\Example.%_currentfolder%\Example.dll"
```